# php_printer.dll can't connect to network printer

Tags: php, dll, printing

I have installer php_printer on my server.
xampp 5.5.19 and php 5.5.19.

I'm using this code:

```
<?php
$printer = ("\\\\192.168.80.117\\Canon iP2700 series");
if($ph = printer_open($printer)) 
    { 
        echo "connect";
       printer_close($ph);
    } 
    else "Couldn't connect...";
?>
```

When it runs, I receive this error:

> Warning: printer_open(): couldn't connect to the printer [\192.168.80.117\Canon iP2700 series] in C:\xampp\htdocs\tes\index.php on line 3

If I change `$printer` to my local printer, it can connect without trouble... Why?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem.

Apache doesn't have right to connect to network printer because of windows authentication.

In `services.msc`, search for Apache and right click on it.

Open log on tab then fill in the credential.